# Windows XP left permissions issue

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, ntfs, windows-xp

I have 2 HDs on my computer, one of them was part of an old XP computer (as a secondary drive) where all my photos and stuffs were shared over the local network.
Now this computer runs only Ubuntu 16.04 and it has no problems with opening and reading the folders created by XP in an NTFS HD, but when i try to share the folder over the samba network and try to access the folders via a different computer and/or my KODI media center, it keeps me asking for a username and a password, but the old XP computer had no password.

I am not new to ubuntu and this is the first real problem i have with samba, i tried every possible set of pass and username samba should/could have put as default but nothing

The problem was completely ignored when the PC were running XP but still, when i used to try to connect with newer versions of XBMC(i could connect without problems with my old XBOX 2002 edition with old XBMC) the same problem occured.

Standing with my knowledge the only solutions should be to reset the permissions of the files but i tried and it didn' t work at all, and even trying to move the data to different folders doesn' t give any help.

Thanks in advance for everyone who will answer!

Comment: You need to configure samba so that samba can access the files there and then it should work.

Comment: @Natim the folder and sub-folders are property of the user but everyone has access to both read and write and it should include samba, if he needs to have the ownership then, i' ll try